# Best practices in certificate management

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, x509certificate

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where each user have their own A1 certificate (usually a password protected pfx file from a CA) used to sign in server side some documents.

The two options I see is to store the pfx file in the server and save the password for import into C# X509Certificate2 class each time or import the certificate to Windows Storage and access the certificate by serial number using the C# X509Store and others. The two have pros and cons (security, maintenance, performance).

Anyone has expertise with this kind of situation and could share some tips?

P.S.: Sorry for the general format of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone has expertise with this kind of situation and could share some tips?

Well, the thing that jumps out at me is storing the PFX/PKCS #12 certificate and private key *with* the password on the server. It kind of destroys some security properties, and probably provides deniability to something that's suppose to offer non-repudiation.

> The two options I see is to store the pfx file in the server and save the password...

I believe there's a third. The user downloads the documents from the server; then the user signs the documents; and finally, the user uploads the detached signature to the server. I think that's the customary workflow.

Another bad idea I see on occasion is to have the server send the hashes of the documents, and then the user signs them without knowing what he or she signed. The user should always calculate the hash himself/herself. Schneier even recommends the user slightly modify a document to ensure its not under the attackers control and prone to a collision.

---

> ... import into C# X509Certificate2 class each time or import the certificate to Windows Storage and access the certificate by serial number using the C# X509Store and others.

This is a design detail. I don't believe there's enough information to make any useful comments.

---

> Best practices in certificate management

The cool thing about certificates is they are public, and not sensitive. So there's not a lot of practice surrounding them. The PKI that the certificates are used in is a different story, though.

Pick a hash and modulus to meet your future needs, like SHA256 and 3072-bit RSA modulus.

Short lived certificates (30 days or so) promote small CRLs, which is a benefit to some clients (those who check revocation). OCSP is better, and OCSP stapling is even better.

Its OK to re-certify the same public key if the certificate is rotated frequently because key continuity seems to be a more desirable or useful property than key rotation.